# Get/Set column names after join

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I got a query made like this:

```
String query="select* from Table1 T1 join Table2 T2 on T1.id=T2.id where T1.id=someid";
```

Now, I execute it like this:

```
Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query);
```

but now I'd like to refer to ResultSet columns like 'T1.colName', as T1 and T2 have columns with the same name...is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the meta data?

Comment: After having tried it, if you notice that it doesn't work, I think you'll have to replace the `*` with the names of the columns you need, while using aliases (`AS`) to rename the columns that have a same name.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually assign aliases to columns with the same name, or you will need to access them by column index. The tablename or table alias is **not** part of the column label When a `ResultSet` contains multiple columns with the same label, it will return the first column with that label:

> When a getter method is called with a column name and several columns have the same name, the value of the first matching column will be returned.

(from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)